# Subdomain creation on each user creation

Tags: 7, subsites

How to create subdomain for each user creation(seller role)? there is subdomain module as well as domain access module. can any one elaborate how to use sub domain module w.r.t user creation? Thanks in advance.

**Note: My Apache is configured to accept all subdomains**

Comment: can u be more specific?

Comment: Do you want Drupal to respond for subdomains, while having Apache set to direct *.example.com to Drupal at example.com? Or do you need actual vhost creation?

Comment: @molot: Actual sub domain should be created on user creation.for example (www.google.com site means i need www.ram.google.com sub domain need to be created on user creation).

Comment: @RamDoss.R Yea, but what do you mean by that? New DNS record? New Apache vhost in it's config? Or simply Drupal starting to respond to it?

Comment: @molot: I am using ubercart module in this site, and i want to have new sub domains for each user with  role seller(user creation).is it possbile for   drupal to handle with out any dns record or apache vhost ?

Comment: If your DNS settings and Apache settings allows you to use anything as a subdomain and get to your Drupal, you are half way there ;) So, if your site is example.com try to go to http://test.example.com and http://anyrandomstring.example.com - if you can see your Drupal site (no matter if it's main page or 404 or error) you are good and we can solve this on Drupal side. If not, you need to consult your sysadmin.

Comment: @molot: 127.0.0.1 ram.test.dev
127.0.0.1 subdomain-test.ram.test.dev

vhosts file:-
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/ms/"
ServerName ram.test.dev
ServerAlias *.ram.test.dev   

still i cant able to get sub domain module working ?its throwing error as `Subdomain error: ram.test.dev and subdomain-test.ram.test.dev did not resolve to the same IP address. Your DNS may be improper`. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: OK, so your Apache **is** configured to accept all subdomains. Good. Please add this info to your question, and I'll try to post answer when I'll have time to do it properly. EDIT: It seems configured OK. Why this does not work? I have no idea. Server Fault might know.

Comment: what i need is while user registers(role seller alone), at that time i need to create (username.site.com) like tat. Is it possible with sub domains?

Comment: I am myself found the solution for this question after lot of digging and thanks for putting this question on hold :) .The solution is domain rules module.With the help of domain rules i am  able to create Subdomain on each user creation.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not aware with your requirement in detail, I would suggest the [Subdomain](https://drupal.org/project/subdomain) module, which allows you to achieve this kind of functionality.

> Automatically creates subdomains and places content on them. There are
>   4 modes:
>
> User: e.g. "Mary" and content at http://mary.example.com
>
> Taxonomy: e.g. "Seattle" and content at http://seattle.example.com
>
> Organic Group: e.g. "MyGroup" and content at http://mygroup.example.com
>
> Content type subdomains: e.g. "News" content at http://news.example.com

The other module is the [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/Domain) module.

Comment: The questioner already mentioned both the modules you listed as solution is not actually helping him. Its utter useless to grab some of the content available in Subdomain module and paste it as answer.

Comment: @pown The question is edited three times. I already had answered it before it edited :)

Comment: @mohit_rocks: its ok not a problem,i found the solution and also mentioned it above.hope it helps some one :)

Comment: @mohit_rocks: pardon my language. I also had same prob'm and Ram's answer(Domain rules module) helped me to get what I wanted.